# Can I control the context menu on a link in htmlText when using Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, hyperlink, contextmenu, htmltext

I created a Flex application with a `textArea`. I'm populating the `textArea`'s `htmlText` property.

I have a context menu on the `textArea`, but I don't see how to make a different context menu when the user right clicks on a `<a href...>link</a>`.  Can I control the context menu for a link displayed inside of the `htmlText` of a `mx:TextArea`?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell it isn't possible to change the right-click context menu on links in a textArea.  It seems that someone else is also having similar problems:
http://www.blog.lessrain.com/as3-texteventlink-and-contextmenu-incompatibilities/

Please go file a bug:
http://bugs.adobe.com